# What is the underlying technology behind SAQL? Can it be used in Apex?

Tags: apex, query, einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

We have been introduced to SAQL, which seems to be a powerful high performance query tool with large number of records. I want to know if we are able to use the underlying technology behind it in our Apex code to do queries over millions of records, do some basic processing, and insert/update new records using another tool like Batch Apex. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_overview_intro.htm) doesn't talk about the possibility of using SAQL in Apex (which I assume is not possible directly) but I hope there is a way to make it work. The only other alternative that I have found for large number of data records is Async SOQL.

Comment: You cannot use SAQL (or SoQL, for that matter) to insert records the way you do it in SQL.

Comment: Further, SAQL is used in the Einstein Analytics (formerly Wave) product, not in vanilla Salesforce. Are you using Analytics, or are you looking for a general purpose high data volume solution?

Comment: Thanks David. But what powers SAQL? I'm thinking if there's a shared undelying technology that we can access directly on Salesforce, we can use that.

Comment: You can't access SAQL to manipulate Salesforce objects on Salesforce.

Comment: You might want to look into Big Objects - they both are build more or less on NoSQL. The core difference is that you need to predefine indexes which in turn make the table perform better and lack of transactions. Here's an extremely good write up on Big Objects: https://albasfdc.com/2017/11/21/10-thoughts-about-big-objects/

Comment: AFAIK Salesforce uses Cloudera's backend instead of Oracle for the things mentioned - SAQL, Big Objects and Async SOQL.